# Using google maps to get name of places instead of creating markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Places API to make the following request

```
var request = {
       bounds: boxes[searchIndex],
       types: ["city_hall","local_government_office","library"]
   };
```

then I make a request

```
service.radarSearch(request, function (results, status) {
   if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
     alert("Request["+searchIndex+"] failed: "+status);
     return;
   }

   for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
      //don't create marker but simply print the name of that place ???
     // var marker = createMarker(result);
   }
```

I want to simply print the name of that location instead of creating a marker. How can I do that. I tried `result.name` but I am getting `undefined` 
       });

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for [radarSearch](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#radar_search_requests)

> A Radar Search lets you search for places within a specified search radius by keyword, type or name. The Radar Search returns more results than a Nearby Search or Text Search, but the results contain fewer fields. You can call PlacesService.getDetails() to get more information about any of the places in the response.
>
> The PlaceResult objects returned by radarSearch() include only the following properties:

- geometry.location
- place_id
- reference (Note: The reference is deprecated in favor of place_id, as described in the deprecation notice on this page.)

**There is no name property**.  To get that you have to do a details request on each result returned.

To get the name property in the result without making an additional details request, use  [nearbySearch](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests), which is limited to 60 results, in batches of 20.

Comment: As noted on Google official documentation:

Notice: Radar search is deprecated as of June 30, 2018. After that time, this feature will no longer be available.